# Unable to compile with make | fatal error No space left on device

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, makefile

Situation: Just installed linux, Trying to learn to code c. Gets set up with sudo apt-get install build-essential. Open nano type in my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        puts("Hello World.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

open another console tab, types in make ex1
then my world spins downward into the darkest abyss i have yet to experience on my first linux distro.

```
ragnar@ragnar:~/Documents/C$ make ex1
cc -Wall -g    ex1.c   -o ex1
ex1.c:7:1: fatal error: error closing /tmp/cc8d7Oap.s: No space left on device
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ex1] Error 1


ragnar@ragnar:~/Documents/C$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5       4.0G  3.8G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.9G  8.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.4M  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G  8.1M  7.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb2        96M   29M   68M  30% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb7        11G  248M  9.5G   3% /home
```

all help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693131/gcc-no-space-left-on-device

Comment: should i expand my root partition? or seperate the tmp and root partitions?

Comment: Seperating `/tmp` from `/` definitly is a good idea.

Comment: Should i still expand the size of my root, might it cause me more problems down the line somewhere?

Comment: Expanding mostly never is a problem .. ;-) See my updated answer on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The partition containing the root folder (`/`) is 100% full. The root folder currently also contains the `/tmp` folder, which is used during compilation to store temporary files. As the root folder and with this the tmp folder is full, this fails.

To get around this either add more space, or reorganise the existing one.

As a workaround do

```
mkdir ~/tmp
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
```

and retry compilation.

---

A flexible way to organise a file system is using seperate partitions for

```
/
/usr
/home
/var
/tmp
```

A lazy approach would be to link `/tmp/` to `/var/tmp`. This however might cause issues as in terms of clean-up the OS might handle the content in `/var/tmp` different from the content in `/tmp`. That is the content of `/tmp/` would get deleted on each boot where as `/var/tmp` wouldn't.

Comment: How might I go about reorganizing my partitions? The same way i did the tmp? or is that just a redirect?

Comment: This would be another question. Before posing it you might like to read around, probably starting here: http://serverfault.com/q/449395

Answer (score 0):

here is my output from df:

```
[857][rkwill.rkwill-desktop: /home/rkwill]$ df -h -T
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      910G   16G  849G   2% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs  3.4G  4.0K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     684M  1.5M  683M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     3.4G   96K  3.4G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   68K  100M   1% /run/user
```

You may notice that my disk partitioning is very simple (the swap partition is ~6gigs)

The actual disk is 1 tera byte.

tera byte disks are very cheap now-a-days.

Your whole disk seems to be ~33gig.  That was great back in the days of MS-DOS and early versions of linux.

However, my ubuntu 14.04 linux is only using ~26gigs of the disk

(and I have numerous utilities, add ons, pictures, videos, source code for several projects, etc etc.)

suggest making the initial install (until you know more about how everything will work) with only the / and swap partitions.

When I use multiple partitions, I organize similar to @alk suggestion, with the addition of a partition for windows, for /lib and for /etc.

Such partitioning allows faster access on my servers, with multiple hard disks, and safer fail modes, but is hardly worth it for my desktop.

My desktop has a multi partition external tera byte hard disk for backups.

Comment: I the days of MSDOS GB-disks where not around. I remember my 1st 20MB disk which, converted to EUR, cost me something like 400EUR. Yes MB, not GB ...:-) Ahyes, those were the days when this guy had stated "*640KB [RAM] ought to be enough ...*" and the Linux version started with a `0`.

Comment: @alk I had the exact same thought, "33GB for MSDOS? That would have been unbelievable!"  A 10MB disk was $300. A file size of 1MB would have been massive. A file size of 1GB was unthinkable.